# How do I move the System Reserved, it was installed on the wrong HD, and I need to remove that HD. Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a machine with two physical HD.
Disk 0 - 2TB HD.
Disk 1 - 64GB HD SSD.

I installed Server 2008 on Disk 0.
Now, I need to disconnect Disk 1. Because I didn't install it there, I thought there would be no problem.
But when I did so - the computer stopped working.

So, I reconnected and started investigating.
It turned out that windows installed on Disk 1 as part of the setup something it likes to call "System Reserved" 100mb MTFS.
How do I move it to Disk 0 - without reinstalling the server?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move the partition over to the other drive with a partition manager, something along the lines of Acronis, Patition Magic and maybe even gParted. You may need to resize the existing partitions on Disk 0 to get things to fit.